# How to check whether single and multiple words exist in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

I need to check wether a WORD (not just any string) exists in a sentence.
For example "or" in the string "these are words" would return False, whilst "are" would return True.

When checking for a single word its easy. Split the sentance string into a list, and check for desired word in list.

```
def word_search(word):
    string_split = string.split()
    if word in string_split:
        print("The word is in the list!")
    else:
        print("The word is not in the list!")
```

This works perfectly well for single words. Problem is if I want to check for example "these are" in the string "these are words" (as long as one of the words given exists in the string the output should be True). When splitting the string into a list, I can only check for one word at a time, and splitting the word/s I want to check causes issues with checking a single word.

I'd rather not use RegEx and keep it to "vanilla" python, but I'm struggling here.

Comment: why not just check if the original string is a substring in the searched string? (no splitting involved)

Comment: @Andrew Because then `or` *will* be found in `words`…

Comment: Regexen *would* solve this problem very elegantly… replicating what `\bthese are\b` does in pure Python will be… more code than the regex version…

Comment: Out of curiosity, why avoid RegEx? This is a perfect place for it...and I'm not sure what you mean by "vanilla" Python, since the `re` module is part of the standard library.

Comment: Well to be perfectly honest @JRiggles , RegEx seems complicated, and I don’t have complete understanding of base python on its own even, so I’d like to stick to just “base” logic if that makes sense?

Comment:  http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: @deceze also [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the intersection method on sets....

```
target_words = ['hi', 'there']
target = 'hi there friend'
if len(set(target.split()).intersection(target_words)) > 0:
    print('at least one target word found')
else:
    print('none of the target words found')
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's acceptable to OP to find words in *arbitrary order*…

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point

Comment: All I want is the output “True” if ANY of the words given exist in the string, so the order shouldn’t matter.

Comment: This seems to work! I'll implement it into my code and see if it's reliable, but it seems to solve my problem, thank you! I hadn't heard of intersections before, how do they work?

Comment: So a problem remains. This word-searching is part of a class, and will be used elsewhere. The target_words are user-input based. So how would I append multiple input-words to a list if theyre added in one string? Ideally the input can be a single string of multiple words, and they're split appropriately for searching. If I just do .split on the string, single-word inputs wont work anymore.

Comment: Eureka, I’ll do a check for wether the string contains spaces or not, and then only do .split if a space is present! Should work, hopefully.

Comment: If in check for " " did the trick! Now both single and mutltiple words work, in any order, giving desired results. Thank you very much! Solved!

Comment: Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Would this work;

```
import itertools
word = "these are"
string = "these are words"
string_split = string.split()

for L in range(len(string_split) + 1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(string_split, L):
        if word == " ".join(subset):
            print("The word is in the list!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are after:

```
def word_search(string, words):
    for word in words.split():
        if word in string:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the any() function like so:

```
searchQueries = ["these", "are", "words"]

if any(query in string for query in searchQueries):
    print("The word is in the list!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def word_search(word, string):
    string_split = string.split()
    if any(x in word for x in string_split):
        print("The word is in the list!")
    else:
        print("The word is not in the list!")
```

Comment: Sleek solution, but sadly when "word" is one True and one False word, the result is False. I.e. when checking for "these are" in "these are words" it gives True, but "these arent" gives False. This makes sense, but I want to have the function return True if ANY of the given words are true, thats where I'm struggling.